# Camera not showing only blank black i'm using google vision

Tags: android, camera, vision, google-vision

hi guys i need your help. i made  app recognition Text from Camera using google vision i got error when i open my app, my camera doesn't work, it shows me black screen, and textview at bottom. how can i resolve it.

this is my code android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </activity>


    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="ocr"/>
</application>
```

this is my mainactivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SurfaceView cameraView;
TextView textView;
CameraSource cameraSource;
final int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RequestCameraPermissionID: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
    if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
        Log.w("MainActivity", "Detector dependencies are not yet available");
    } else {

        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();
        cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                RequestCameraPermissionID);
                        return;
                    }
                    cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });

        textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {

                final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if(items.size() != 0)
                {
                    textView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                            for(int i =0;i<items.size();++i)
                            {
                                TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
                                stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                                stringBuilder.append("\n");
                            }
                            textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
```

im already debuging etc but still not work 
thanks for help me guys